# Which memory can be accessed using Meltdown and Spectre v1/v2?

Tags: windows-10, memory, meltdown, spectre

I understand that Meltdown can access kernel memory as the programs on Windows at least share the same virtual memory space. We have a patch for this to unmap as much kernel data as possible. Can Meltdown access other processes memory?

But what about Spectre 1/2? What memory can it access? Can it access kernel memory as Meltdown? Can it access other processes memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned briefly in the [meltdown paper](https://meltdownattack.com/meltdown.pdf), modern operating systems just map all physical memory into the kernel virtual address space. This means that for most intent and purposes you can assume access to kernel memory = access to any other processes' memory.

The [projectzero blog post](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.ca/2018/01/reading-privileged-memory-with-side.html) shows that specter can be used to access kernel memory.

Variant 1 can read kernel memory by running arbitrary code in kernel mode inside a sandbox(for example with the [Berkeley Packet Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter)) and then use the vulnerability to access memory outside the sandbox.

Variant 2 can access it because branch prediction works across security context so a branch in user mode can be used to train branch prediction in kernel mode.

Comment: Didn't know all the other apps are mapped in kernel space. This means meldown/spectre can access any other apps.

Comment: This means x86 system are safer than x64 systems?